# No me funciona el try catch C#

Tags: c#, try-catch

Estaba desarrollando un pequeño programa para sacar unos datos de un archivo de excel. Lo que pasa es que al recorrer un data grid view y acceder a un dato me trae un  NullReferenceException. Este lo encierro en un try catch pero que sin embargo no hace absolutamente nada. El programa de igual forma crashea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes tildado que se interrumpa.. si queres que vaya por el catch, destilda eso, porque estas en modo debug y eso pasa sobre el modo debug...

Comment: mete todo tu codigo dentro de tu try catch

Comment: Lo estas depurando? Has probado a quitar el check de la ventana emergente que indica que se va a interrumpir cuando encuentre el error?

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco porque no funciona tu try catch pero puedes usar esta funcion que devuelve una cadena "" si el valor en el celda del datagridview es nulo

```
public String valor(DataGridViewCell celda)
    {
        String respuesta = "";

        if (celda.Value != null)
        {
            respuesta = Convert.ToString(celda.Value);
        }

        return respuesta;
    }
```